# iPhoto slideshow question about music

Tags: macbook-pro

My slideshow has two songs. The first one is a great beginning but too long. It's 3:57 minutes. I want it to only play for 2 minutes. How do I keep the song and limit its time?

Comment: You could - as a workaround - trim it in any music editor like GarageBand, Audacity and I think even iTunes.

Comment: It seems that the only option on the slideshow in iPhotos is to upload music from iTunes. hmmmmm.

Comment: I don't have iPhoto anymore, so I can't try it. But what is the problem then? Edit the audio to your fitting length (e.g. with GarageBand), export it as mp3 or whatever you like and import it to iTunes. Then, you should be able to see it in iPhoto.